# How do I make Git diff ignore version number changes?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Is there a way to remove version number change noise from a Git diff [like this one](https://github.com/keith/Xcode.app-strings/commit/9502c601cad31ef452c4cd6e8ece3982345fba1d)? Specifically if a line only contains changes from one number to another can I set up Git diff to ignore it?

Comment: Do those files even belong in source control?

Comment: Perhaps the -g option helps?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Git is used to track changes to the strings inside an third party app. I don't think your question is relevant to mine. In the interest of keeping this comment on topic: Is there a way to automatically unstage these changes?

Comment: You can specify a custom diff command for git, which could then filter such things out, but the versions that are mentioned in your example are all over the place and may be hard to write filters for.

Comment: Smudge and clean filters? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this can be achieved using `git-diff --word-diff-regex=[^0-9]` ([see [^0-9] in action](https://www.regextester.com/96723)). For a more complex pattern you'll need a more complex regex but, [except recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133684/1977018), *everything is possible with regex*.

From [Git - git-diff **--word-diff-regex** documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---word-diff-regexltregexgt)

> **--word-diff-regex=**
>
> Use < regex > to decide what a word is, instead of considering runs of
>   non-whitespace to be a word. Also implies `--word-diff` unless it was
>   already enabled.
>
> **Every non-overlapping match of the < regex > is considered a word. Anything between these matches is considered whitespace and ignored(!)
>   for the purposes of finding differences.** You may want to append
>   `|[^[:space:]]` to your regular expression to make sure that it
>   matches all non-whitespace characters. A match that contains a newline
>   is silently truncated(!) at the newline.
>
> For example, `--word-diff-regex=.` will treat each character as a word
>   and, correspondingly, show differences character by character.
>
> The regex can also be set via a diff driver or configuration option,
>   see [gitattributes[5]](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) or [git-config[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). Giving it
>   explicitly overrides any diff driver or configuration setting. Diff
>   drivers override configuration settings.

## See also

- [Git - git-diff **--word-diff**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---word-diffltmodegt)

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction. I updated the regex to ignore `.` as well and added -U0 from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159394/ignore-all-whitespace-changes-with-git-diff-between-commits to remove context. And I ended up with this: `git diff -w -U0 --word-diff-regex=[^0-9\.]`

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark as solved if that's the case :).

Comment: Will do. Just waiting on the timer to expire in 50 minutes. 

Comment: @SteveMoser that timer just expired.

Anyway, how do I now suppress the chunks that have no changes left? I still get them in my output albeit without the change highlighted. I have a script updating 100 files and as long as that only changes numbers, I'm fine but I don't want to scroll through hundreds of empty chunks.