# How to make git diff ignore <version>x.y.z</version> lines?

Tags: git, git-diff

I am producing a diff between two branches with a command like

```
git diff <branch-1> <branch-2>
```

Beside the actual code differences, there is a big noise because of many changes in the form

```
-       <version>42.2.0.12</version>
+       <version>42.3.0.10</version>
```

I would like to see a clean diff, where those differences are either excluded or non-highlighted.

I already checked two similar SO questions, which were of no help:

1. [How to make git diff ignore comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527215/how-to-make-git-diff-ignore-comments): leads to a non-working solution
2. [How do I make git diff ignore version number changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135986/how-do-i-make-git-diff-ignore-version-number-changes): is better, as it ignore the 'x.y.z', but leads to a *messy* git diff, where I cannot really see the lines that have changed because it reports the changes on each single word.

For instance, in the second case, I used

```
git diff -w --word-diff-regex='[^<version>(0-9\.)</version>]' <branch-1> <branch-2>
```

Now that the premise is set, the question is:

- Is there a way to use git diff and just remove some unwanted differences such as `<version>x.y.z</version>` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ignoring changes matching a string in git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878622/ignoring-changes-matching-a-string-in-git-diff)

Comment: The suggested link is similar to the link 1. in my question: it uses the `-G` flag. Such flag does not work as requested in my question, by filtering out the commits not matching. If a solution with -G exists, I would like to know which RegExp can be used to match all the lines not containing <version>x.y.z</version>. And this, is the actual core of the question, which is specified in the title. Hence, the question is still is unanswered.

Comment: Closing this question as duplicate is poor review. In my question, the link 1. points to a SO solution using `git diff -G <regex>` . I wrote that it leads to a non working solution. The link suggested by the reviewer has a solution `git diff -G "your pattern" > matching_diff.txt` which is the same as the one I pointed, but it writes to file - which makes it even worse, as you lose highlighting of the other diffs.

Comment: @TarekDakhran : no, it does not solve the issue.

Comment: Unless you can construct a way to use `git diff -G <negative regex that matches OTHER lines>`, then no, git does not have a built-in way to do what you're asking.

Comment: Also note that this - `[^<version>(0-9\.)</version>]` - is a character set, it matches everything but the symbols `<`, `v`, `e`, `r`, `s`, and so on, it is not a patten that matches *text* other than `<version>...`. it will match on one symbol, so as long as a line has at least one character that is *not* in that character set, it will match your regex. You will have to work harder with something like a negative lookahead to construct your regex, if at all possible.