# Ignoring newlines in git diff

Tags: git

How can I get `git diff` to ignore changes like:

```
a + b + c
```

to

```
a +
b +
c
```

i.e, treat all sequences of whitespace as identical for the purposes of diff?

Note that given `file1`:

```
a + b + c
```

and `file2`:

```
a +
b +
c
```

running

```
git diff -w --word-diff-regex=[^[:space:]] file1 file2
```

gives:

```
diff --git a/file1 b/file2
index baaa7f9..1ded6d8 100644
--- a/file1
+++ b/file2
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
a +
b +
c
```

not an empty diff as expected. Although the hunk presented actually has no changes (as in no lines begin with `+` or `-`). Is there a way to remove hunks with no changes?

Comment: `git diff -w`??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore \*all\* whitespace changes with git-diff between commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159394/ignore-all-whitespace-changes-with-git-diff-between-commits)