# git giff|merge does not ignore any blanks as same

Tags: git

I mean, my problem is exactly the contrary of [Ignore *all* whitespace changes with git-diff between commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159394/ignore-all-whitespace-changes-with-git-diff-between-commits/39581294)

(Ubuntu, git 2.17.1)

```
$ git checkout development
$ git diff development master
...
-// some text
+    // some text
...
```

Okay, no critical diffs listet, automatic merge should be run successfully. But wtf is that:

```
$ git merge master
up to date.
```

I want merge to exactly the same! Earlier projects, that I'm worked on with Windows, git found and merge absolutely all that trivial differences. What is the reason why Git no merge this differences, even though "git diff" find that?
Here is my

```
$ git config --list
diff.tool=meld
difftool.prompt=false
difftool.meld.cmd=meld $LOCAL $REMOTE
merge.tool=meld
mergetool.meld.cmd=meld $LOCAL $MERGED $REMOTE --output $MERGED
credential.https://....git.beanstalkapp.com.username=gitusername
color.ui=auto
user.email=gitusername@server.de
user.name=gitusername
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://....git.beanstalkapp.com/liebesschloss.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.development.remote=origin
branch.development.merge=refs/heads/development
```

Anyone can support me to configure and/or use git to take care of ALL white spaces? 
Maybe I can't see a tree through all the forrest?

Answer (score 0):

> I want merge to exactly the same!

That's not what `git merge` does.

Step back for a moment and consider that the goal of `git merge` is to *combine work*.  Suppose that you and some other guy—let's call him Fred—start with the all the same files.  One of them is some file that uses `//` comments.

Fred changes some code down at line 55.  Meanwhile, *you* notice that there's a mis-spelling in a comment:

```
// some tuxt
```

should read:

```
// some text
```

and, perhaps, should be indented differently.  So *you* fix line 12.

Now, at some point in the future, you obtain Fred's commits.  You run:

```
git diff <mine> <fred>
```

or:

```
git diff <fred> <mine>
```

One of the things that shows up different is the comment-fix *you* made.  **If `git merge <fred>` simply made your file *the same* as Fred's, that would *undo your spelling fix*.**  Hence, `git merge` *does not use* the result of `git diff` of the two branch tip commits.

#### So, what *does* `git merge` use?

Git's merge operation depends on finding the *merge base*.  The merge base is, essentially, the common commit that you and Fred both started with.  *Finding* the merge base is a matter of examining the *commit graph*.

The commit graph emerges by the fact that each commit has a *parent* commit.<sup>1</sup>  The parent of your current commit is the one that was in place just before you, or whoever, *made* your current commit.  That commit's parent is the one that was in place before it, and so on.  Git works by following these backwards-pointing parent chains.  For (much) more on this see many of my other answers to similar merge questions.

In particular, though, you ran:

```
git merge master
```

and got:

```
Already up to date.
```

This particular message occurs when your branch is *ahead of* master.  That is, suppose the commit graph looks like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- master
               \
                I <-J   <-- development (HEAD)
```

Your *current commit* is commit `J` (`J` here stands in for the big ugly hash ID), whose parent is commit `I`, whose parent is commit `H`.  So if, in our little "combine work" setup, `master` represents Fred's latest work, and `development` represents yours, then the command: *Combine Fred's work with mine* is trivially satisified: you both started with Fred's latest, commit `H`.  You made some changes since then.  Git just keeps exactly what you started with.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some commits have *two* parents.  These commits are slightly special, in that they are *merge* commits.  At least one commit in the repository has *no* parents, because it was the very first commit and could not have a parent.

---

#### Viewing the commit graph

There are many ways to view the commit graph, including with various GUIs, or the tcl/tk based viewer `gitk` that comes with Git.  These tend to be better, in some ways, than the text-graph viewer built directly in to Git, but that viewer is always present and does not depend on external software the way these graphical viewers do.

Run `git log --graph` and Git will generate a graph.  Because `git log` output is long, you won't really see very much on a page, so you might want to instruct `git log` to use one line per commit:

```
git log --oneline --graph
```

That will show you the graph starting with your *current commit* and working backwards.  To make sure that Git tells you that the first commit *is* your current commit, you may want to add the `--decorate` option, or turn on `log.decorate` in your configuration:

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph
```

(or `git config log.decorate auto`, which implies `--decorate` automatically when using `git log` at the command line).  And, to tell Git to start working backwards from *all* branches and *all* tags, you may want to add `--all`:<sup>2</sup>

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

Or in this particular case you might use:

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph master develop
```

to tell Git: *starting from both `master` and `develop`, show me commits along with their parent relationships.*  That will let you view the graph, and will inform you (somewhat, at least) about what Git will see as the merge base between `master` and `develop`.

---

<sup>2</sup>"All Decorate Oneline Graph" is a very useful combination, and can be remembered via the mnemonic: [*get help from A DOG*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075021/1256452), from [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452).