# git --name-status ignoring all whitespace

Tags: git, diff

I'm trying to determine which files have non-whitespace changes.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33159593/800619), which only shows the non-whitespace differences, but when I add `--name-status`,the files with whitespace only changes still show up.

Is there someway to get this to work?

Comment: I have the same problem. More specifically, it seems that as soon as you use any command, which will not require git to compute the full diff, the `--ignore-*` flags don't seem to have an effect anymore. 
I guess that's an optimization within git, but as soon as the ignore flags are being used, this optimization shortcut should be avoided in my opinion.