# WinMerge - ignore all whitespace including newlines and formatting changes

Tags: git, winmerge

How can I ignore "code style" changes while using WinMerge as a difftool? Specifically across two commits.

So that

```
thing
{
  a,
  b
}
```

and

```
thing { a, b }
```

would be treated as identical.

Essentially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159394/ignore-all-whitespace-changes-with-git-diff-between-commits/33159593) question, but for winmerge rather than diff.

**.gitconfig**:

```
[diff]
    tool = winmerge
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "winmerge"]
    cmd = "$HOME/scripts/winmerge.sh" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
[mergetool]
    prompt = false
    keepBackup = false
    keepTemporaries = false
[merge]
    tool = winmerge
[mergetool "winmerge"]
    cmd = "'C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe'" -e -u -fm -dl \"Local\" -dr \"Remote\" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED" "$REMOTE"
```

(`winmerge.sh` just calls `WinMergeU.exe -e -u -wr "$1" "$2"`)

None of the [command line options](https://manual.winmerge.org/en/Command_line.html) seem to fit, and I think line filters won't work because they are per-line.

Comment: Diff tools are traditionally line-based as programs are written as text in lines. You're basically asking for a diff at the tokenized & normalized level, not at the textual level. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75800278/269126), but it's not directly usable answer, just an explanation of the conceptual and practical problem.

Comment: @Lumi yes, and [JD Frias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62825323/3554391) gets closest to that idea. My "solution" since I asked this question has been to enforce clang-format rules in my team :).

I could envision a theoretical tool which runs a formatter but keeps track of the original source locations, and then does a diff on the formatted text but shows the user the source-mapped originals for editing. Similar to how you can debug transpiled javascript by stepping through the typescript. I'm not sure that tool exists currently, as you said.

Comment: Coming back to this two years later: There is no option in WinMerge to do this. I have found [difftastic](https://difftastic.wilfred.me.uk/) to do what I was actually asking here, which is syntax-tree-based diffs. It does so at the cost of speed and memory, so I end up having both winmerge and difftastic in my gitconfig and switch between them depending on my needs. For my given example (with .cpp extensions), difftastic prints "No syntactic changes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question with the benefit of more time:

- **This is not possible with WinMerge**
- `difftastic` does this for read-only diffs at the cost of speed and memory
- No tool that I'm aware of does writable diffs (e.g. conflict resolution) while showing semantic-based diffs

### Not-quite-there solutions:

> Ignore blank lines; Ignore carriage return differences (Windows/Unix/Mac)

This ignores line feed differences, and full blank line differences, but does not compare files semantically. It does help in certain simple cases.

> Line filter `^\s*$`

Same as "Ignore blank lines"

> `.gitattributes` formatter with `textconv` for specific file types

This is the closest option for read-only diffs, with the downsides of:

- needing to define a separate attribute (and formatter) for each file type
- displaying the formatted versions of the files rather than the original

### My current solution

- For conflict resolution, use WinMerge as-is with as much of the "ignore" options turned on as possible. Resolving conflicts with formatting changes is a massive pain no matter what you do, so try to isolate formatting changes to their own merges.
- For diff viewing, use [difftastic](https://difftastic.wilfred.me.uk/) which uses tree-sitter to compare code on an AST level rather than a textual level
- When `difftastic` is slow or hogging memory, fall back to `diff`/WinMerge/VSCode

Answer (score 20):

This option works for me:

WinMerge -> Edit -> Options -> Compare -> General:
Ignore blank lines;
Ignore carriage return differences (Windows/Unix/Mac)

etc.

The answer was taken from https://superuser.com/questions/174275/can-i-compare-only-file-contents

Comment: This doesn't do it if you have one file with some blank lines inserted and the other one doesn't AND there are character-level differences between the non-blank lines. In that case, "Align similar lines" is needed. And these other options seem redundant to that one (except the line conversion probably).

Comment: The question is how to do get the identitcal diff result when comparing the same text where in one file it is in a long line and in the other with separated line (to fit a column length for example).

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `.gitattributes` for your file. This would run a tool to normalize/beautify/prettify both files before comparison.

This will run `.json` files through `json_pp` before compare:

```sh
echo "*.json diff=json" >> .gitattributes
git config diff.json.textconv json_pp
```

Check out git documentation for details: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Source: https://t-a-w.blogspot.com/2016/05/sensible-git-diff-for-json-files.html

Comment: This definitely does work to show semantic diffs, but I would still rather a winmerge-specific option that still shows the original files, but doesn't highlight the code style differences. Running a formatter can get a little slow for larger cpp files, and I'm also worried about the issues it could cause when editing diffs and saving them. I don't want to accidentally commit formatting changes if I don't need to.

Comment: I use Beyond Compare has custom rules for comparison, and tons of other features. It is paid though, well wroth it in my opinion #notsponsored

Answer (score 1):

In addition of ignoring white spaces/blank lines/...etc. Do the following

- Go to Tools->Filter
- Select "Linefilters" tab
- Check Enable Line Filters
- Add the following expr, and make sure it is checked
  ^\s*$

[image]

-Refresh the comparison

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this will just filter out blank lines, which is not what I'm asking. I wanted the behavior of [difftastic](https://difftastic.wilfred.me.uk/), which does AST-based semantic diffs. I use that tool now if I need that, and winmerge when I don't.